# Any research on the impact of copywriting speech on sign up buttons?

Tags: buttons, signup-signon, speech-input

I keep finding this kind of speech in landing-pages' sign up buttons:

[image]

Are there any available resources that help me find out why do I actually **feel to click this button more than others?** Some of them even make me smile...

Comment: I can't point to any particular studies but it has a lot to do with two things you can research respectively. First is the idea that humans largely overlook things they've seen before unless they want to see it. You might not be real inclinded to sign up for a site because your eyes glance over the signup button if it simply says "Sign Up." unless you were going out of your way in the first place to sign up for that site. It draws your attention by being something different.

Comment: Interesting, you have a point on saying that users are becoming blind on call-to-action elements when they look all the same... @jackmce

Comment: I didn't actually mean to leave that as a comment and then an answer. I ran out of space and forgot to delete the comment. I can't point the blindness of the user directly to UI design but I recently took a class on complying with OSHA regulations and industrial safety. A big thing the guy teaching the course pointed to was they've found that warning and caution sings placed in the same place and same generic warning over and over get overlooked so you should try to make them topical to what you're warning or showing an employee. Same can probably be said for signup buttons/options.

Comment: @JackMcE, interesting. Don't you love the way UserExperience, which has gotten a lot of meaning through IT's, applies to everything we experience even in the offline world? I wonder what would the tangible products we use everyday be if the UX was taken into account as we do now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't point to any particular studies but it has a lot to do with two things you can research respectively (with a little work because you'll get a lot of results about social media and other unrelated topics).

First is the idea that humans largely overlook things they've seen before unless they want to see it. You might not be real inclined to sign up for a site because your eyes glance over the signup button if it simply says "Sign Up." unless you were going out of your way in the first place to sign up for that site. It draws your attention by being something different.

Secondly filler words like awesome, can't handle and others plant the seed of something cool and draw attention. Its a bold statement and bold statements draw attention and can have promise for something being good if you sign up.

Those two things are what draw attention and make those style of buttons or statements more and more common place. How many more people it makes sign up I'm not sure and don't care to speculate because getting users to sign up for services has always been a hard part of the process but if such a thing draws a little more attention to the signup process while not making the signup button hard to find for someone looking to signup without having to be drawn in is to your developmental benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Something thats's conversational or personal has always attracted users so far. This is the reason why attractive copies and taglines sell. You may not guarantee acquisition but yes, you will figure out the difference when you do A/B testing, with different sign up panels! The one that speaks gets most acquisition.

Comment: one needs to be carfeul though, because using an specific language may not fit possible new users. Any ideas on how to identify the specific _speech_ to be used?